# QuerySelector returns null. How to get querySelector to return <h1>Hello</h1>?

Tags: javascript, html

On this page and in the videos I watched, everything worked and returned <*h1> Hello <*/h1>. However, Chrome still returns null. I will be very grateful for your help. I'm already desperate.

```js
let myH1 = document.querySelector("h1");
console.log(myH1)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>###</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script will be running before the DOM content is technically "loaded" - historically you might encapsulate the logic within a [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event handler - but these days you can also signal that your script is meant to be executed after the content by adding the [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute to the `script` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the script is being loaded before the HTML, so the `querySelector` does not found anything.

To avoid this problem, you have to load the script *after* the HTML `body` **or** create a listener to execute when the page loads. Here is the examples:

With the Javascript loaded after the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>###</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

With the listener

```js
function onLoad() {
    let myH1 = document.querySelector("h1");
    console.log(myH1);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!